# Is indexing more values in the same amount of rows causing performance problems in my case?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have an `audit` table, which has an `id` as primary key, a `user_id` as `foreign key` and one-dimensional indexes for `tableId`, `tableName` and `parentTableId`. So:

- `id`: `primary key`
- `user_id`: `foreign key` to a `table` where users are stored, showing who did the action for the record in the `audit` `table` represents
- `tableId`: `bigint` indexed `column`, not a `foreign key`, because the `audit` `table` stores the `audit` of all tables and `tableId` represents a given record in a `table` where an event occurred
- `tableName`: `varchar(255)` indexed `column`, noting where the changed record belongs to
- `parentTableId`: `bigint` indexed `column`, not a `foreign key`. The parent `table` is determined by application logic based on `tableName`

There are a bunch of other `column`s as well and the table has approximately 20 millions of records. Now, `tableName` has around 20 possible values and in the case of `'concert'` the value of `parentTableId` was -1, however, the `parent` table of a concert is `'tour'` (I know I can improve performance by creating a `table` for `table` names and using a `foreign key` towards that in the `audit` `table`, but this requires large refactoring, which will not necessarily be approved). Even though the old `audit` records had a correct `tableId`, but an incorrect `parentTableId`, I was able to `update` the audits `where tableName = 'concert' and parentTableId = -1` to the correct `parentTableId`, using the relation between the `concert` and `tour` `table`. So far, so good.

However, the client reported a slowdown when `concert` records are being created. Since virtually all my other changes were related to the displaying of the `audit` page, which is not being executed at the time when a concert record is being created, it is safe to assume that none of my other changes caused slowdown. To be precise, some minor changes were done in terms of storing the `audit`, which actually runs when a `concert` record is being created, these are small textual and calculation tweaks, which are impossible to cause slowdown when a `concert` record is being stored. So, either the slowdown was by accident, or my large `update` on audits caused the slowness afterwards due to the increase of variance in indexed values.

I'm not giving the `update` code, because that's just changing the `parentTableId` to its correct form and it was executed only once, it was not running when the client started to do the testing, so it is irrelevant from our perspective here.

So I wonder whether the `index` could be the cause of the slowdown. We know that different `tableId` values can be associated to the same `parentTableId`, but the invert is impossible.

My question is: is the indexing causing the slowness in the case of the write in my case and if so, would a change of the indexes improve performance for write?

I'm thinking about changing the order of the indexes, so just after `user_id` constraint is checked, to handle `parentTableId`, then `tableId` and finally `tableName`. Should this in theory improve performance?

Comment: Don't add an index unless you would actually be using it.  It's possible that the indices could be slowing down an insert/update.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is an old system where the indexes were added a long time ago and they are being used by the filters.

Comment: how many indexes you have related to the table  concert  ??? how may insert in table concert  you have in a minute?

Comment: @scaisEdge I am only wondering about the audit table here. I am analyzing the concert table as well, but it would overcomplicate the question.

Comment: the slowdown  is for an insert on the table concert  right?  .. so the first candidate  for investigation is this table

Comment: @scaisEdge the slowdown on the table audit. There were changes, the concert table's insertion was left unchanged.

Comment: @scaisEdge insertion to audit is being executed when a concert is created.

Comment: Then you are thinking at a side effect .. ... for this are possible several issue ..  not  only indexes ..  some .. lock .. for example  .. some concurrence on same resource ..

Comment: @scaisEdge I am thinking about the big picture, but asking a question about only a part of it, as the other parts are clear for me.

Comment: Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE` instead of turning that into prose!